# Отправка POST c boundary

Tags: mime, ajax

Добрый день. Надо отправить POST запрос через ajax.

Заголовки:

```
Content-Length  : postDataText.length,
Content-Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------148736758665
```

Отправляемый код:

```
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[name][1]"

Tester
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[name][2]"

Заголовок вакансии
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[category_rid][1][1]"

1
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[category_rid][3]"

раздел для размещения вакансии
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[region_rid][1][0]"

39
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[region_rid][3]"

город работы
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[jobtype_rid][1][76]"

76
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[jobtype_rid][3]"

вид занятости
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[salary][1]"

-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[comment][1]"

-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[experience_type_rid][1]"

0
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[education_rid][1]"

0
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[gender_rid][1]"

0
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[age_from][1]"

-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[age_to][1]"

-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[description][1]"

<p>123123123123</p>
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[manager][1]"

1479110
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[is_active][1]"

0
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data[hot_job]"

0
-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="locHref"

-----------------------------148736758665
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="btSave"

Сохранить вакансию
-----------------------------148736758665
```

Сервер не видит никаких данных в массиве $_POST

Comment: а как вы данные принимаете? по каким параметрам?

Comment: по идее. В POST должны набится переменые.  
К примеру:   
$_POST['btSave'] = 'Сохранить вакансию';  
Все это дело я отправляю через Ajax.  
    request.open(url,'POST',true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',postDataText.length);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------148736758665');
    request.send(postDataText);